# WSO2IS - Link to login to facebook

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have to create a webapp with login to WSO2IS and Facebook capatibilities.

I configure WSO2IS to allow basic auth from WSO2IS and FB without problem.

But what is the link I should provide to the login to facebook bouton ?

I configured travelocity to try to understand but the login to facebook bouton is
something like :
https://localhost:9443/commonauth?idp=FacebookIdP&authenticator=FacebookAuthenticator&sessionDataKey=a9d4856d-e5a8-4731-b381-3c93f7f344d6

And the sessionDataKey seems to be coming from a workflow step...

Hope to be clear enough to be understood, let me know if I should provide more 
description.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

For example in Travelocity, the login link URI is as follows. It will be redirected to FB login page once click on the link.

http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com/samlsso?SAML2.HTTPBinding=HTTP-Redirect

If you are using multy option login, you can send the IDP as a query param with request as follows

http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com/samlsso?SAML2.HTTPBinding=HTTP-Redirect?fidp=FacebookIDP

Comment: Thank for the anwser but it is not a call to WSO2IS that you propose it is the call to travelocit and it is a sample.
What is the first call to wso2is that travelocity is sending and that I need to send from my app ?

Comment: It is like     https://localhost:9443/samlsso?SAMLRequest={request}&fidp=FacebookIDP

Comment: OK sounds better, but how to construct the SAMLRequest ? I'll deep into the samlsso servlet... but that should be documented in wso2is documentation...